# Laravel 5.1 + Dingo API + JWT token

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, token, dingo-api

I use Laravel 5.1 + Dingo API + JWT token.
My route is:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function($api) {

$api->post('authenticate', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@authenticate');
$api->post('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@logout');
$api->get('token', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@getToken');
$api->get('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@test');

});

$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {

    $api->get('authenticated_user', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@authenticatedUser');
    $api->get('getvoucher', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@index');
    $api->post('/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@store');
    $api->put('/update/{key}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@update');

});
```

Now when I run at Postman to get token everything is fine, so I get:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMDQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBwLmRpbmVhbmRnaWZ0LmNvbS9hcGkvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE1NDE3NDQ0LCJleHAiOjE1MTU0MjEwNDQsIm5iZiI6MTUxNTQxNzQ0NCwianRpIjoiNzk2dXZCQnhreGtpSDJneiJ9.XJiH3v95-FJOVYT_XfWIbQZ_lHqYDmWRR-jIHp6uoag"
}
```

but now I want to retrieve auth user and I have function protected by middleware, but I get:

```
{
    "message": "Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header.",
    "status_code": 401,
    "debug": {
        "line": 113,
        "file": "/home/dgadmin/public_html/test/vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/Auth.php",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\UnauthorizedHttpException", ... ETC...
```

What is a problem here and how to oslve this issue?

Comment: localhost everything works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the token in the url ?

```
http://url?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMDQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBwLmRpbmVhbmRnaWZ0LmNvbS9hcGkvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE1NDE3NDQ0LCJleHAiOjE1MTU0MjEwNDQsIm5iZiI6MTUxNTQxNzQ0NCwianRpIjoiNzk2dXZCQnhreGtpSDJneiJ9.XJiH3v95-FJOVYT_XfWIbQZ_lHqYDmWRR-jIHp6uoag
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your app's config `config/api.php` if you have the authentication provider registered. If this doesn't work update your question with it's contents.

```
'auth' => [
    'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT',
],
```